# Update query could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, update

I'm trying to do a simple update query and I'm getting this error:

> The multi part identifier "customers.customer_name" could not be bound

Query:

```
Update Suppliers
Set City = (select s.city
    From suppliers AS s
       Where s.supplier_name = customers.customer_name)
Where Exists (select c.city
    From customers AS c
        Where c.customers_name = Suppliers.supplers_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is slightly off. In SQL Server, here is how I would perform this update:

```
UPDATE s SET s.city = c.city
FROM dbo.Suppliers AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c
ON s.supplier_name = c.customer_name;
```

From [my most popular answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212).

Remember to [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and also it is often easier to just call those columns `name` instead of prefixing each with the table name.